# How to find inverse laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

$$
F(s) = \dfrac{6s+9}{s^2-10s+29}
$$

How do you solve the inverse Laplace transform of this above equation?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: My first thought was partial fractions.  Then I noticed that in $s^2-10s+29=(s-5)^2+2^2=t^2+2^2$ the sign before $2^2$ is "$+$", you're looking at something involving trigonometric functions.

Comment: It depends, is this for a math class or an engineering class?

Comment: "Solve" is the wrong word.  I might have said "How do you find the inverse Laplace transform of the function above?".  The word "equation" is also wrong.

Comment: Somebody pulls out the Bromwich integral...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
F(s) = \dfrac{6s+9}{s^2-10s+29}=\dfrac{6s-30+39}{(s-5)^2+4}=\dfrac{6s-30}{(s-5)^2+4}+\dfrac{39}{(s-5)^2+4}=6\dfrac{s-5}{(s-5)^2+4}+\dfrac{39}{2}\dfrac{2}{(s-5)^2+4}
$$
Then
$$
\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{F(s)\} =6e^{5t}\cos{2t}+\frac{39}{2}e^{5t}\sin{2t}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $s^2-10s+29=(s-5)^2+2^2$, which implies that
$$F(s)=\frac{6s+9}{s^2-10s+29}=\frac{6(s-5)+39}{(s-5)^2+2^2}.$$
Therefore, 
$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}(F(s))=6\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{s-5}{(s-5)^2+2^2}\right)
+\frac{39}{2}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{(s-5)^2+2^2}\right)\\
=6e^{5t}\cos(5t)+\frac{39}{2}e^{5t}\sin(2t)$$
by [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LaplaceTransform.html).

Answer (score 0):

$$
\underbrace{s^2-10s+29 = (s-5)^2+2^2}_{\text{completing the square}} = t^2+2^2
$$
So
$$
\frac{6s+9}{s^2-10s+29} = \frac{6(s-5)+39}{(s-5)^2+2^2} = \frac{6t+39}{t^2+2^2} = 6\frac{t}{t^2+2^2} + \frac{39}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{t^2+2^2}
$$
Now look at each term separately.